# Using OneHotEncoder in multiple columns with repetead categories amongst columns?

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding, dummy-variable

Imagine I have 4 categories in 3 columns but these categories are repeated amongst columns. For example....

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'a', 'd'], ['a', 'c', 'd'], ['b', 'd', 'a']])
   0  1  2
0  a  b  c
1  b  a  d
2  a  c  d
3  b  d  a
```

and when I transform, I get 8 columns, when I should be getting only 4 (one for each category (a, b, c and d).

```
ohe = ColumnTransformer([('ohe', OneHotEncoder(categories='auto', sparse=False), [0, 1, 2])], remainder='passthrough')

df2 = ohe.fit_transform(df1)
```

being df2 the eight column categories, but I want to obtain only four... one for each 'a', 'b', 'c' and 'd' categories distributed in my columns.

Is there any way to obtain this output?

```
Out[17]: 
   a  b  c  d
0  1  1  1  0
1  1  1  0  1
2  1  0  1  1
3  1  1  0  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

> I want to obtain only four... one for each 'a', 'b', 'c' and 'd' categories distributed in my columns

You can use `value_counts` applied on columns axis:

```
>>> df1.apply(pd.value_counts, axis="columns").fillna(0).astype(int)
   a  b  c  d
0  1  1  1  0
1  1  1  0  1
2  1  0  1  1
3  1  1  0  1
```

---

*Old answer*

Some explanations about how encoding working:

```
>>> df1
   W  X  Y  Z
0  a  b  c  c
1  b  a  a  b
2  a  c  a  b

>>> df1.nunique()
W    2  # [a, b]
X    3  # [a, b, c]
Y    2  # [a, c]
Z    2  # [b, c]
```

For column `W`, there are two different values `[a, b]` so you need 2 columns to encode them: For instance:

```
   a  b
a  1  0
b  0  1
```

For column `X`, there are three different values `[a, b, c]` so you need 3 columns to encode them. For instance:

```
   a  b  c
a  1  0  0
b  0  1  0
c  0  0  1
```

*Note the identity matrix.*

Let's use `pd.get_dummies` rather than `OneHotEncoder` to a better understanding:

```
>>> pd.get_dummies(df1)
   W_a  W_b  X_a  X_b  X_c  Y_a  Y_c  Z_b  Z_c
0    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1
1    0    1    1    0    0    1    0    1    0
2    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    1    0
```

The question is why you want to get only 3 columns?

Comment: What I actually need is not to differentiate W, X, Y and Z... my output should be three columns (a, b, c). In the example I only have 3 rows of data, but  have thousands of them.

Comment: i edited the question in order to see if it explains better